# delete word templates in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I created word templates for an entity

How can I update/delete/edit existing templates that I created for an entity?

I tried to navigate to Settings->business->Templates but its not showing the ones that I created

[image]

Answer (score 1):

within templates instead of selecting Word or Excel and you want to delete selecionar edit or update

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEsUv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If the word templates are uploaded directly from the entity list, it will be under "personal templates",  to delete them we need to go to advanced find and search for the template and delete it
If its under business template, go to settings-> Templates(under business) and delete it